# Do you have to use Urban Airship to build push notifications using PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, urbanairship.com

Do you have to use Urban Airship to build push notifications into a PhoneGap app?

Everything I've found so far mentions Urban Airship....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't have to use Urban Airship for this. Urban Airship is actually a third party 'framework' which communicates with C2DM (Androids Cloud To Device Messaging) for you.

But, it can be quite difficult to build this by yourself. That's why alot use Urban Airship at the moment. It provides an easy way to add notfications to your Android app, aswell as for your iPhone or Black Berry app.

So basically Urban Airship provides you one framework and you're able to build Push Notifications for three platforms.

It also comes with an online backend which allows you to easily send the Push Notifications to all users.

So my advice is, check it out. I do recommend it.

For an indept tutorial on how to implement this for Android, then check the following site which helped me alot:

http://phpmyweb.net/2011/10/04/use-urban-airship-for-your-android-app/

Comment: If one were to not use UrbanAirship, how would I go about that?

Comment: @iUsable check out this tutorial [link](http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/)
 and there is one for Android linked there as well.